# interpolate missing values with respect to step column in R

Tags: r, pandas, tidyverse, interpolation, missing-data

I have a panel data that is designed for survival model.
Some observations have missing data. however, the intervals are not constant.

Here is example of it:

| t | value |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |
| 10 | 8 |
| 15 | 12 |
| 18 | **NA** |
| 20 | 3 |
| 25 | 9 |
| 30 | 15 |
| 35 | 21 |

As you can see `t` intervals are 5 units. However we have a record that `t` is 18 and it is missing the value. I want to interpolate the values column with respect to the column `t` in R.

Do you have any suggestion?
It would be better if the method can support non-linear interpolation.

P.S.

- The data is relatively huge, so generating a panel with small steps is not possible with my hardware.
- I can handel python as well, but R is more convenient as the interpolation happens mid analysis in R.

Answer (score 0):

**In R**

- Use [`na_interpolation`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/imputeTS/versions/3.3/topics/na_interpolation) and pass the desired parameters, such as

  ```
  library(imputeTS)

  df$value <- na_interpolation(df$value, option = "spline")
  ```

---

**In Python**

- Use [`pandas.Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) and pass various `methods` as follows, such as `quadratic`

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  df['value'] = df['value'].interpolate(method = 'quadratic', limit_direction = 'both')
  ```
- Use [`sklearn.impute.KNNImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer), such as

  ```
  from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

  imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors = 2, weights = 'distance')
  df['value'] = imputer.fit_transform(df[['value']])
  ```

Comment: I know these methods. The issue here is that they assume that the distance between data points is the same. However, in my case, the distance of the NA rows is different from the rest of the time series.